# C: Printing out the value and memory location of each element of an array using pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have generated a random array inside the main function, How can I properly print it out using a separate function and inside the function print out the value and memory location of each element of that array using pointers. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(int *pointertoArray, int *Size);

int main (void)
{
 srand(time(NULL));
 int array[10];
 int *pointer = NULL;
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     array[i] = rand();
     *pointer = array[i];
     printArray(*pointer,size);
 }
}
void printArray(int *pointerToArray, int *size)
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nValue %d = %p ",i,*pointerToArray);
        i++;
    }
    while(i < size);
}
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
    value 1 = 0x7fff0815c0e0
    .....
    value 10 = 0x7fff0815c0ec
```

Answer (score 3):

- `int *size` should be `int size`. You don't pass a pointer, and you don't need a pointer.
- Actually, `size_t size` would be more appropriate.
- The call to `printArray` should be located after the loop. You only want to print the array once.
- `printArray(*pointer, size);` should be `printArray(array, size);`.
- `pointerToArray` should be named `array` or `pointerToInts`.
- The value of the element is `pointerToArray[i]`, not `i`.
- The address of the element is `pointerToArray+i`, not `*pointerToArray`.
- The loop in `printArray` should be top-tested. (No reason for it to be bottom tested, so play it safe.)
- `main` is declared to return an `int`, but doesn't.

We get,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(int *array, size_t size);

int main() {
   srand(time(NULL));
   int array[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      array[i] = rand() % 1000;
   }

   printArray(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
   return 0;
}

void printArray(int *array, size_t size) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      printf("Value @ %p = %d\n", array+i, array[i]);
   }
}
```

Alternative:

```
void printArray(int *pointerToInt, size_t size) {
    for (; size--; ++pointerToInt) {
       printf("Value @ %p = %d\n", pointerToInt, *pointerToInt);
    }
}
```